# Graph API calls via Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook provides a [nice guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) on how to authenticate to the Facebook API via the client-side JavaScript SDK. The following JavaScript code will print out the user's data.

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I have an authentication system up and running with the following FB login button

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1" scope="user_relationships,friends_relationships,user_photos,friends_photos"></div>
```

How do I get user_relationships, friend_relationships, user_photos, friends_photos using a similar JavaScript API call? I am not really sure what to replace '/me' with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'r application requires permissions to access user_photos, user_relationship_details, friends_relationship_details,friends_photos
(**[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)**).
Once the user grants them, then you'r app will be able to access them.

For **user relationship status** `/me?fields=relationship_status` and for **friend's relationship status** `/<friend-user-id>?fields=relationship_status`

For user albums you can use `/me/albums` and `/me/photos/` for the photos in which the user was tagged and for friend's photos and albums the same as above